# Partial change of value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database where the values of a column are of a type

Say for example In the table `Date` the column is called `Day`

```
Monday November 17 2012
```

I want to change all instances containing `Monday` with it's equivalent in another language changing it like 'Monday in my language' November 17 2012.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you really storing them as text?

Comment: It is the automated Date_Name generated by the analysis services project on the BI VStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem I just found the answer:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TimeDim]
SET [dbo].[TimeDim].Date_Name =REPLACE(Date_Name, 'Tuesday', 'Tuesday in my language')
WHERE [dbo].[TimeDim].Date_Name LIKE '%Tuesday%'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. add a new column
2. update the new column based od the old column
3. drop the old column
4. rename the "new" column with the old name.